# (AJAX) How do I make a jQuery POST delete confirmation button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a ajax `POST` delete method with a jQuery modal popup which deletes a course just when I click the Delete button. The popup shows up, but when I close the popup and refresh the page, I see the record is deleted.

Is there a way to implement a Confirmation button with jQuery popup, where it only gets deleted when the user clicks "Yes" and refreshes the page automatically?

**Html**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CourseID }, new { @class = "deletebtn", @id=item.DepartmentID })

<div id="dialog" title="Delete Department" style="display: none">
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete this Course?</p>
    <button id="confirm-deletion">Yes</button>
    <button id="abort-deletion">No</button>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $(".deletebtn").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#dialog').dialog();

            var btnobj = $(this);
            var id = btnobj[0].id;

            $('#confirm-deletion').on("click", function() {

                //$('#dialog').dialog();

                //var btnobj = $(this);
                //var id = btnobj[0].id;
                //console.log(btnobj);

                var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
                var data = { id: id, __RequestVerificationToken: token };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("Delete","Course")",
                    data: data,
                    //ajaxasync: true,
                    success: function () {
                        console.log("success");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("failed");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What gerrit said, define the click functions for each button in your dialog and move your code with ajax into a function. Call the function in the click.

```
 $( ".selector" ).dialog({
  buttons: [
    {
      text: "Ok",
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-heart"
      },
      click: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }

      // Uncommenting the following line would hide the text,
      // resulting in the label being used as a tooltip
      //showText: false
    }
  ]
});
```

[jquery dialog docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons)

Comment: Can I have the page refresh automatically after the deletion? Right now, I can only verify that the record  is deleted after I refresh the page manually.

Comment: You can add 'window.location.reload();'  to refresh the page after your ajax success or if you have access to the 'id' in the ajax success you can also select the item and remove it without page reload '$('#' + id).remove(). You could even pass the id from the dialog all the way to the ajax success.

Answer (score -1):

You open the dialog, but that does not keep the AJAX request from being executed. Why would it? What you do is simply opening a dialog and then sending your AJAX request immediately. You need to execute the request when a button inside of the modal dialog is clicked, not when it is opened.

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Delete Department" style="display: none">
  <p>Are you sure you want to delete this Course?</p>
  <button id="confirm-deletion">Yes</button>
  <button id="abort-deletion">No</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#confirm-deletion').click(function() {
  // Send request here
});
```

Comment: Do I need the `preventDefault()` for both the function, like the click to open it and then the click to actually delete the record?

Comment: Firstly, I have to refer to Martinas answer as the correct one, as she obviously knows the jQuery dialog API better than me. But to answer your question: I do not think you need any `preventDefault()` as long as you do  not click on submit buttons in side of a form.

Comment: I made the `confirmation-delete` button to send the AJAX request under it, but the dialog box does not close automatically upon clicking "Yes" and I have to refresh the page manually.

Comment: I again refer to Martinas answer, do it like she suggested. Simply add your AJAX request in the click event before the `$( this ).dialog( "close" );` line

Comment: I did that, but it is still not working in the refreshing aspect. Thanks for the assistance. I going to have to dig deeper into this.

Comment: In the success function, where you output "success" to the console, refresh the page via `document.location.reload()`